# Is it possible to use Excel functions to evaluate the result of a function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I have a formula in `I2`:

`= "=" & "'" & $H2 & $I2 & E2 & "'!" & "$C$2"`

It combines the directory, filename, sheet name, and cell location.

Now I'd like to evaluate the **result** of that formula in `J2`. Is it possible to do so without VBA or with just a bit of VBA? I need to be able to fill down `I2` to `I1000` and I personally prefer a non-VBA approach.

For example, let's say the **result** of `I2` is:

`='R:\20180220\[Test.xlsb]'!$C$2`

Is there a way to actually show the value of that cell in `J2`? Note that **workbook Test.xlsb is closed and won't be opened** (because I have thousands of workbooks and cannot open all of them).

I tried `EVALUATE(Range.Formula)` and `ExecuteExcel4Macro()` in VBA, and tried to wrap them with a UDF, but both failed.

Comment: Try INDIRECT() but that will require that the workbook be open.

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner thanks for the reply! Yes I tried that too, but the files have to be closed, pity...I'm willing to use a UDF though.

Comment: If you tried a UDF, then it might be useful to post what you tried and describe what happened when you ran it.

Comment: @TimWilliams Good idea, I'll update the post after the meeting, thanks!

Comment: `[J2].Formula = [I2].Value`, or change `"$C$2"` to `"$C2"` and `[J2:J1000].Formula = [i2].Value`. Might be better to query the closed workbook with Power Query or Microsoft Query

Comment: @Slai Thanks! This actually works in VBA! BTW I'm using Range("J2").Formula = Range("I2").Value.  Is it possible to put it into a formula? I'm not familiar with Power Query, but I'm looking into different files in different folders (name of folder and file are decided by H2, I2 and E2 though.

Comment: not in Excel formula, and I guess the only way in VBA UDF would be with `ExecuteExcel4Macro()` or ADO, but that seems like too much work. You can query multiple files in a folder with Power Query https://support.office.com/en-us/article/combine-files-in-a-folder-with-combine-binaries-power-query-94b8023c-2e66-4f6b-8c78-6a00041c90e4, but you can modify the query in the advanced editor to query multiple folders https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-advanced-query-power-query-9f08ceac-c949-4408-baff-6a7eaa183e11

Answer (score 1):

Here's a kludge that may work for you.

1. Create the formulas as in your current post. Note that the result in your post **lacks a reference to a tab/worksheet** --- you likely need to update your formula to include a worksheet. The formula I used in my tests is `= "=" & "'" & $PATH & $FILE & $TAB & "'!" & "$C$2"` (the same as yours but with a field added for the $TAB).
2. Copy/paste special values the results. This replaces `= "=" & "'" & $PATH & $FILE & $TAB & "'!" & "$C$2"` with `='C:\PATH\WORKBOOK\TAB!$C$2` to give the correct formulas. Annoyingly they do not calculate automatically.
3. To force an update of the calcs, `F9` doesn't seem to work, so select the results and do a **mock** find/replace, say replace $C$2 with $C$2. This doesn't change the formulas but gets the recalc going. You might also be able to just save, close and re-open the workbook.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I decided to use VBA instead so that's it. BTW I also tried to refresh and save/close a while ago but it didn't work.