# Strange occurence with VBA Evaluate and For loop

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using Evaluate() in a loop, and everything goes fine except the first evaluate in the whole loop.

```
RowBegin = 98 
For RowCount = RowBegin To RowBegin + 23   'Total 24 rows per site per day
    If (RowCount Mod 4 <> 1) Then
        Cells(RowCount, 6).Value = Evaluate(Cells(RowCount, 10).Value)
        Cells(RowCount, 7).Value = Evaluate(Cells(RowCount, 11).Value)
    End If
Next RowCount
```

Please note that 1 of the 4 rows is skipped because I have a formula there. All the Evaluate() works perfectly except for the first one:

```
Evaluate(Cells(98, 10).Value)
```

This one shows a #REF error. I double checked the formula and it is alright. In fact, even the next one within the same loop works:

```
Evaluate(Cells(98, 11).Value)
```

This is the formula I put in Cells(98,10):

```
='R:\20180220\[Filename.xlsb]Summary'!$D$2
```

And this is the formula I put in Cells(98,11):

```
='R:\20180220\[Filename.xlsb]Summary'!$D$3
```

However, if I modify the code to:

```
RowBegin = 98
For RowCount = RowBegin To RowBegin + 23   'Total 24 rows per site per day
    If (RowCount = RowBegin) Then
        Cells(RowBegin, 6).Value = Evaluate(Cells(RowBegin, 10).Value)
        Cells(RowBegin, 7).Value = Evaluate(Cells(RowBegin, 11).Value)
    End If
    If (RowCount Mod 4 <> 1) Then
        Cells(RowCount, 6).Value = Evaluate(Cells(RowCount, 10).Value)
        Cells(RowCount, 7).Value = Evaluate(Cells(RowCount, 11).Value)
    End If
Next RowCount
```

Then everything works.

Stranger is, this also works:

```
RowBegin = 98
For RowCount = RowBegin To RowBegin + 23   'Total 24 rows per site per day
    If (RowCount = RowBegin) Then
        Cells(RowBegin, 7).Value = Evaluate(Cells(RowBegin, 11).Value)
    End If
    If (RowCount Mod 4 <> 1) Then
        Cells(RowCount, 6).Value = Evaluate(Cells(RowCount, 10).Value)
        Cells(RowCount, 7).Value = Evaluate(Cells(RowCount, 11).Value)
    End If
Next RowCount
```

Please note that in the first IF, it actually does not touch Cells(RowCount, 6)!

I'm scratching my head because I think the first piece of code and the second one is exactly the same (because when RowCount = 98 it is not skipped anyway). Does it have anything to do with the loop or the Mod operator?

Comment: What happens when that first formula is evaluated? BTW it's usually a good idea to use the `Worksheet.Evaluate` form, which you can scope to a specific worksheet, and not the `Application.Evaluate` version which defaults to the ActiveSheet.

Comment: Why do you need to `Evaluate` the formulas? don't the cells contain the value you need?

Comment: @TimWilliams Sorry I forgot to mention that I got a #REF error. I checked the worksheet and $D$2 does exist.

Comment: @Mat'sMug It's a bit complicated. My cells actually contain formula, not text, because I need to fill down the whole sheet. So in the cell you will see something like = "=" & "'" & $H98 & $I98 & $E98 & "'!" & "$D$2", this will produce a text and will then be evaluated with the EVALUATE() formula. I'll see if I can use the worksheet.evaluate instead.

Comment: @Mat'sMug continuation of [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48892588/is-it-possible-to-use-excel-functions-to-evaluate-the-result-of-a-function)

Comment: @TimWilliams I tried Worksheet.Evaluate but still doesn't work (works for the others, just not the first one). I wish I could upload the file but it's kind of sensitive...I'll see if I can create a similar workbook.

Comment: Just a general hint about the `Worksheet.Evaluate` thing.  The same scoping advice applies to other parts your posted code too - it's a good idea to never use unqualified `Range()` or `Cells()` calls.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the hint! Cells() part is OK because I'm using the same one in the same loop. BTW I found something stranger, if you have time, could you please look at the part I just edited (starting from "Stranger is, this also works")

Comment: instead of ending the first IF try using Elseif.  You are doing both Ifs and maybe throwing off what you expect.

Comment: @ScottCraner Actually the first IF doesn't do anything, because I begin the counting from row 98, so the first IF is redundant. However, I need to keep the first IF to avoid the #REF error. That's what I don't understand. Stranger is, it works as long as I keep the first IF, even if it doesn't contain Cells(RowBegin, 6) = Evaluate(Cells(RowBegin, 10).Value).

Comment: Actually I'm surprised this works at all.   For me Evaluate ing a reference to a closed wb always returns #Ref error.  An alternative that does work is writing the string to the cells .Formula property. You can overwrite with the value after that if required

Comment: @chrisneilsen I forgot to mention that I gave up writing code for closed wb and wrote code to open the wb before doing anything to them. It's clumsy but at least got the job done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first time it kind of opens the external reference - but not in time - and throws an error, and then from then on it is okay.  So the reason the `IF` works and not the `ELSEIF` is because when you use the `IF` it redoes it again, while the `ELSEIF` it doesnt.  This explains all that weird behavior.  Just keep a dummy line in there to open it, like:

```
RowBegin = 98 
Cells(RowBegin, 6).Value = Evaluate(Cells(RowBegin, 10).Value) ' Dummy
For RowCount = RowBegin To RowBegin + 23   'Total 24 rows per site per day
    If (RowCount Mod 4 <> 1) Then
        Cells(RowCount, 6).Value = Evaluate(Cells(RowCount, 10).Value)
        Cells(RowCount, 7).Value = Evaluate(Cells(RowCount, 11).Value)
    End If
Next RowCount
```

Comment: Hi I think that's the case. I'll check tomorrow to see if there are better methods. Wish I could program Excel with C++ or Python.

Comment: You could use C# with Interop if you want, but I bet you have the same issue.  Some sort of internal timeout or something with Excel I bet.